# Bitcoin alpha version with 15 minutes block time interval

Tags: bitcoin-core, block-interval, satoshi

> In alpha software prior to Bitcoin's release, the target interblock interval was 15 minutes, and it was reduced to 10 minutes for release.

https://www.reddit.com/r/Bitcoin/comments/56nk94/on_chain_scaling_with_schnorr_signatures/d8lmwco

Where can I find this alpha version for research?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cryddit on Bitcointalk posted some source code that Satoshi supposedly emailed to him. This code contains a target interval of 15 minutes rather than 10. It is in https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=382374.msg4108739#msg4108739. Search for `nTargetSpacing`.

Comment: Interesting, I wasn't aware of this. Apparently it also had 30 day retargetting periods (2880 blocks).